# Basic CSS banner

Tags: css

I'm sure this has to be a really easy one, but I'm having problems!

The effect I want is a block of solid color for a banner or header on each page, in which will be some text. But to add some frills I have made a little graphic to go each side which is simply a small square that fades from the banner color to white. So the overall effect is a nice strip of color with end that gradient out. I hope you get the idea.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="mini_banner_l"></div>
<div class="mini_banner">Hey '.$member_name.', your account is not activated yet !</div>
<div class="mini_banner_r"></div>
```

And my css so far for the job:

```
.mini_banner_l {
background: no-repeat url(../gfx/frills/infobar_end_l.png);
display:inline-block;
}

.mini_banner_r {
background: no-repeat url(../gfx/frills/infobar_end_r.png);
display:inline-block;
}

.mini_banner {
background: #57a7b5;
display:inline-block;
}
```

CSS was never my forte, and maybe there's a better way to achieve this effect (?) but my problem is that nothing shows up atall on the page where the faded ends are supposed to be, but they appear as soon as I add some text in, for example:

```
<div class="mini_banner_l">now it shows</div>
<div class="mini_banner">Hey '.$member_name.', your account is not activated yet !</div>
<div class="mini_banner_r"></div>
```

Any thoughts on how to make it work, or a better way to do it much appreciated :D
Thanks!

Comment: The divs, converted to inline-block, have no content and therefore no width, so no background is painted in them. One cure would be to give them specific width to match the image size.

Comment: also you should specify a height for both the left and right banner.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a width and height to your css like below and change the width & height to the width & height of your graphic.

```
.mini_banner_l {
background: no-repeat url(../gfx/frills/infobar_end_l.png);
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

.mini_banner_r {
background: no-repeat url(../gfx/frills/infobar_end_r.png);
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

.mini_banner {
background: #57a7b5;
display:inline-block;
}
```